# how does data flows through pipe in linux when sorting?

Tags: pipe, sort

suppose I do something like

`cat afile [ | possibly awk or similar to process the file] | sort`

I know data flows something like

```
afile -- stdout -- os buffer -- stdin -- sort
```

When the size of `afile` is small, then maybe `sort` can get the entire contents and sorts them.

However when afile is big, data must flow in chunks.
I know the piped processes run concurrently, so it's possible that sort can receive data and stores them somewhere iteratively.

Does `sort` wait to receive all data before doing the sort?
Possibly writes them onto files.
Then work with those files?

I guess the question can be applied commands other than `sort` that needs the whole data in order to operate.
(How does linux command operate when it receives big data over pipe and it has to get a whole data to perform?, but then it might be too general question to ask..)

Comment: Yes, sort receives data and stores it somewhere. For example GNU sort has options like `-T` to specify the temporary directory to use, `-S` to specify the size of main memory to use. Sort can read in a certain amount of data and write that to a temporary file, read some more and sort that to a tempt file, then do a merge of the temporary files. Remember Unix used to run on machines with main memory measured in **kilobytes**. There is no one answer about how commands operate on big data, it is command specific.

Comment: `sort` is open source; you can just [go look at and see how it's implemented](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c).

Comment: Those kilobyte-order machines also used to manage to sort big volumes using multiple temporary magnetic work tapes (minimum of four tape decks required). If the decks had "reverse read" ability, that could be used to avoid tape rewinds by alternately inverting sort orders. Search for "polyphase merge sort".